# wso2is4.6 claim management

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working on wso2is4.6. 
I am new to wso2is. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I am still blocked.

The first question: when there are multiple claim dialect in system, which claim dialect will be used? Which conditions will make system to choose this dialect instead of another dialect?

The second question: I install wso2is4.6, and install apacheds 2.0 with default (no customization). where can I find corresponding claim mapping?

I know I need to correct the claim mapping, but I don't know how can I find the correct mapping. Can somebody provide the workable claim-mgt.xml base on wso2is4.6 and apache2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding more info to Dulanja's answer,

Q1. In WSO2 Identity server, internally it always uses a claim dialect together with a claim URI to identity a unique claim. Different components uses different dialects to get its claims. Fr an example when adding a new user using management console, relevant(user-manager) component would use WSO2 default claim dialect mentioned above. Similarly if you are doing SCIM related operations, relevant components will use SCIM dialect.

Q2. As mentioned in Q1,  makes the unique claim and where we store that claim's value can be configured in two ways.
i. You can use claim-config.xml in /repository/conf/ folder and you can edit claim-to-ldapAttribute mapping by changing `<AttributeID>` which is given under every  element.
ii. Or you can change claim mappings at runtime using the Claim Management page in management console. Please refer [1] for more info.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Claim+Management

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the posting, the **Q1** is clear to me now. But I am still blocked by **Q2**.

Comment: the **Q2** is caused by mapping. I know I should change the claim-config.xml, I change like below '<Dialect dialectURI="http://wso2.org/claims">
   <Claim>
    <ClaimURI>http://wso2.org/claims/givenname</ClaimURI>
    <DisplayName>First Name</DisplayName>
    .........
......
  </Dialect>'

Comment: The default mapping doesn't work under wso2is4.6 and apacheds2.0.

Comment: did you changed AttributeID element?

Comment: you mean as the values of AttributeID? Its depends on the attributes of your object class of the ldap.

Comment: finally I think I know how it works.  I can configure external apache ds, but that means I need to modify claim mapping file also because the apache ds installation doesn't provide same schema as the embed apache ds. Since I am working on the research, I will start with embed apache ds. Later I will switch to external apache ds.

Comment: Yeah.. that the way it worked. If you happy with either of two answers, please mark it as Accepted.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**
The default claim dialect of WSO2 products is http://wso2.org/claims. This is the underlying dialect of the User Profile view - currently you cannot change this to use a different dialect.

Other dialects are used in different scenarios. As an example http://schema.openid.net/2007/05/claims is used when IS acts as an OpenID Provider. OpenID relying parties (clients) requests attributes using the claim uris specified under this dialect. Other examples are SAMLSSO and Passive-STS flows. In them you have the option to select the dialect that you want to use to send back the attributes to the client.

**Question 2:**
Are you facing a claim-mapping related problem with the new ApacheDS 2.0 LDAP? As far as I know, since WSO2 IS embedded LDAP is also based on ApacheDS, if you point (via user-mgt.xml) to such an LDAP the existing claim-mapping should work without any problem

Comment: Yes, with apacheds with wso2is4.6. After login into carbon, and change user profile, the error is displayed like:        " Error while updating user profile of lory. Error is: One or more attributes you are trying to add/update are not supported by underlying LDAP."

Comment: BTW, does wso2is4.6 takes embed apache DS or not? <br/> I install apache DS seperately. Will this cause issue?

Comment: are you saying I don't need to install apache ds with standard alone installation?

Comment: @richard Yes, IS has an embedded ApacheDS userstore and that is what pointed to by the user-mgt.xml by default. You can use it for testing purposes, but for a production setup it is recommended to use an external userstore.

Comment: yes, I found the jar files of apacheds under identication server.